# Bit representation not being printed correctly for long int

Tags: c++, c++11, binary, bitset

I am trying to print a bit representation of a long integer. I am using this variable as a bitboard for my chess program. However, the representation is not printed correctly. I am using the following code.

```
void displayBoard()
{

    bitset<64>x(fullBoard);
    cout<<x<<fullBoard<<endl;
    for(int i=0;i<64;i++)
    {
        if(fullBoard & (1<<i))
        {
            cout<<"1";
        }
        else
        {
            cout<<"0";
        }
    }

}
```

The first two lines convert it to a binary representation using the `bitset` class and print it.

However, the when I try to do the same using the code in the for loop it gives me the following output:
`1111111111111111000000000000000111111111111111110000000000000001`
The correct output is:
`1111111111111111000000000000000000000000000000001111111111111111`

The value of `fullBoard` that I am using is: `0xFFFF00000000FFFF`

I am compiling using C++11 using the following command: `g++ board.cpp -std=c++11`

Why is this code giving the wrong output? I do not think there is any error in the for loop.

Comment: Ahem, cough! You are aware of [`std::bitset<>::to_string()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/to_string) I suppose?

Comment: I did. But I would need to print the binary representation too. I am printing a chess board.

Comment: _"I did. But I would need to print the binary representation too ..."_ ?!? `std::bitset<>::to_string()` actually gives you the _binary representation_, I don't get what you mean?

Comment: I mean, bitset does print the binary representation, but it does so for the whole number at once. I will be using this bitboard along with others to determine the positions of other pieces.

Comment: Then you could use the `std::bitset<>::operator[]` to access the single bits by index. I simply don't see, why you have it, but don't use it.

Comment: I didn't know of this function!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem is here:

```
    if(fullBoard & (1<<i))
```

This should be:

```
    if(fullBoard & (1ULL<<i))
```

The reason being that `1<<i` is evaluated as an int, which is probably 32 bits in your case, so it's UB once `i` exceeds 31. Making it `1ULL<<i` forces the expression to be evaluated as 64 bits.

Comment: I'll accept your answer as soon as the system lets me.

Comment: @RohitShinde in `(1 << i)`, the `1` is compiled as type `int`. Therefore `(1 << i)` is likewise `int`, and apparently on your platform `int` does *not* have 64 non-sign bits. `(uint64_t(1) << i)` would also work

Answer (score 1):

well your loop looks fine at the first glance, but the constant 1 is not a 64 bit integer, so you have to cast to to a unsigned long long.

Answer (score 0):

> *"Why is this code giving the wrong output? I do not think there is any error in the for loop."*

Well, as others mentioned, there certainly is an error in your for loop, your shift operation respectively. But the good news is, you don't need this `for()` loop, with what you have at hand at already.

> *"The correct output is:"*

```
1111111111111111000000000000000000000000000000001111111111111111
```

The following code

```
unsigned long long fullBoard = 0xFFFF00000000FFFF;
std::bitset<64> x(fullBoard);
std::cout << x << std::endl;
```

works well for me, output is as wanted (see **[live sample](http://ideone.com/nBXrhN)**):

```
1111111111111111000000000000000000000000000000001111111111111111
```

---

Though, the above shown and the other answers considered, you might have a problem with your non disclosed data type of `fullBoard`.
My code example declares it as `unsigned long long`, smaller types will cut off `0xFFFF00000000FFFF` to `0x000000000000FFFF`. Note this to get output for `fullBoard` and `x` consistently.